# NSXMLParser - Parse an XML-file but it shows me the results twice

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, objective-c++

I'm trying to parse a XML-file to a NSMutableArray and show it to the tableview. The problem is when it parse, it add 2 times the results of the parsing in the NSMutableArray. This lead to the tableview showing the result twice. (2 rows in the tableview)

My question is : how can i show one result instead of the twice the same result?

XML-file:

```
 <something>test1234567test</something>
```

The code:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

{   if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"something"])

    [currentname appendString:string];
    [mutarray_xml addObject:currentname];
}
```

i tried :

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
   if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"something"])
   {
      [currentname release];
   }
}
```

### but it shows:

### test1234567test

### test1234567test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do parsing like this correctly, you also need to implement the `didStartElement` method. You should not be adding anything to your mutable array inside the `foundCharacters` method - you should only add something to the array in the `didEndElement` method, because this method indicates that the entire contents of the element has been read.

Comment: Thanks! you were right. it was the foundcharacters method that add the object twice. I added the [mutarray_xml addobject:currentname]; to the didEndElement method. and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

[This post on Big Nerd Ranch](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=48) taught me a lot about using NSXMLParser to parse XML.